# IRibbonUI.invalidate crashes Excel 2010 custom ribbon with COM exception 0x80004005... sometimes

Tags: c#, excel

OK, this is a strange problem we've got with our Add-in for Excel. It works well with Excels 2003 - 2013, but from time to time we get reports about our ribbon disappearing. It seems to happen only on start of Excel 2010 and when opening sheet with our data in it. Our add-in is huge and with problem happening once in a few weeks, there is little I can show you, but I will write some specifics and hope someone can come up with any recommendation on what to do next.

- Right now, it seems to be happening only with Excel 2010 (not absolutely sure about this, though)
- It happens in a callback so it smells like synchronization issue, but not sure if that should be happening at all
- This is the code that gets called in our callback

  ```
  private void SetShowNotConnectedButton(bool show) {
          if(_ribbon != null) {
              _ribbon.Invalidate();
          }
          if(_notConnectedButton != null) {
              _notConnectedButton.Visible = show;
          }
      }
  ```

So my question is, is there any way I don't know of for calling invalidate from a callback, or anyone knows any other issue that might be there with invalidation of ribbon in any version of Excel.